# (Odoo/Openerp) Print due payment report of parent company along with its subsidiary company

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I have a custom module that inherits 'res.partner' object. I added two fields - parent company(many2one) and subsidiary_ids(one2many). I added additional page in partner form where we can create subsidiary company. My question is, is it possible when I print Due Payment report of the parent company, it will also print the due payment report of its subsidiaries? If yes, how?

Comment: Are you using multicompany configuration like described here? https://odooforyou.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/odoo-multicompany-configuration/

Comment: No, I didn't use the multicompany configuration since I'm not quite familiar with it. Why? Is it possible if use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use multicompany configuration, as described in:

https://odooforyou.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/odoo-multicompany-configuration/

you will have all the features for multiple company group, like accounting and reporting, otherwise you will have to rebuild everything yourself, which is not so easy.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Hope it will be useful. Please mark or vote the answer. ;)